# 2010 Chevy Traverse Head Lamp replacement

Tags: chevrolet, maintenance, repair, headlight, traverse

I have replaced the bulbs for my Traverse ( each one ) at least twice in the last 2 years.  Is this normal?  If not, any suggestion to a more permanent fix as it is a giant pain to get to the bulb and replace it?

Comment: Are you driving at night very often? Or using the head lamps at any time?

Comment: They are automatic.  The running lights are fine ( on all the time ) and the headlights come on when its needed.  ( dusk )

Comment: When you change the bulb, are you taking protective measures to ensure you aren't getting any skin oils on to the bulb? (ie: wearing nitrile or cotton gloves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the bulbs in modern cars with composite headlights (usually halogen bulbs), you need to ensure no skin oils or other contaminates get on the bulb during installation. If you do, the life span of the bulb is greatly reduced. It sounds as though you are getting more time out of the bulb than I would expect, but really, you are killing your bulbs prematurely by not keeping them clean during installation.

To ensure you don't get anything on the bulbs, use some nitrile gloves, or if you have them available, use cotton gloves. I suggest nitrile gloves over other forms of gloves (except cotton ... those are the best for this), is because they usually don't have any talc powder on them or anything else which may cause issues with the bulb. They are also very easy to find (even in just a package with only a couple of gloves in them). Cotton gloves are the best to use, but are a lot harder to procure. In a pinch, you could use a paper towel, but you have to be A LOT MORE CAREFUL then you would with gloves on.